# Changing PyQt Text Browser font

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have Python code that launches a GUI, the GUI displays text. I want to format the text i.e. Bold, Italic, change font etc.

```
call.TextBrowserName.append("Lyrics:" + lyrics)
```

Above is an example of how I'm adding text to the text browser (it's a lyric scraping program)

I've tried:

```
call.TextBrowserName.SetFont('Arial')
call.TextBrowserName.QFont(SetFont(Arial))
```

Any help?

Comment: Why try random functions instead of checking the documentation?

Comment: You say: *I've tried*, that's not an attempt, that's just garbage code that you use to signal that you've tried something. With that you discourage the community to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I change the font:

```py
self.text = QTextEdit(self)
self.text.move(100,100)

font = QFont()
font.setFamily(u"Arial")
font.setBold(True)
font.setWeight(75)

self.text.setFont(font)
```

What this does is turn the text into Arial, and makes it bold. To make it italic, try this:

```py
font = QFont()
font.setFamily(u"Arial")
font.setItalic(True)
```

And for underline, you can do:

```py
font = QFont()
font.setFamily(u"Arial")
font.setUnderline(True)
```

Comment: It should be noted that, while for simple use cases it's fine to use `setFont()`, rich text based controls should avoid it, and prefer correct functions (like `setFontFamily()`, etc) used *before* appending new text, HTML tags *or* QTextDocument functions.